# Resampling from a large data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a large `data.frame` of this structure:

```
min.reps <- 1
max.reps <- 3
set.seed(1)
df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:100, function(i) {
  reps <- seq(1,as.integer(runif(1,min.reps, max.reps)), 1)
  vals <- runif(length(reps), 0, 100)
  return(data.frame(id=rep(i,length(reps)),rep=reps,val=vals,stringsAsFactors=F))
}))

head(df)

  id rep       val
1  1   1 37.212390
2  2   1 90.820779
3  2   2 20.168193
4  3   1 94.467527
5  3   2 66.079779
6  4   1  6.178627
```

Each `df$id` has between `min.reps` and `max.reps` observations (`df$val`). In reality instead of 100 ids I have ~5,000,000 ids.

For each `df$id` I'd like to add one more value, sampled from a normal distribution with `mean` and `sd` as the `median` and `mad` over its existing values, respectively.

This is trivial to do this way:

```
add.reps <- 1
all.ids <- unique(df$id)

require(dplyr)
new.df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(all.ids, function(i) {
  id.df  <- dplyr::filter(df, id == i)
  add.df <- rbind(id.df, data.frame(id = rep(i,add.reps), rep = max(id.df$rep) + add.reps, val = rnorm(add.reps, median(id.df$val), mad(id.df$val)), stringsAsFactors = F))
}))
```

But I'm wondering if there's a much faster way to achieve this given the dimensions of my real `data.frame`.

Answer (score 2):

This should be much faster:

```
add.reps <- 1
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$id), function(x) rbind(x, 
         data.frame(id = rep(unique(x$id), add.reps), rep = max(x$rep) + add.reps, 
                    val = rnorm(add.reps, median(x$val), mad(x$val)), stringsAsFactors = F))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so so far:

```
require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
new.df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(all.ids, function(i) {
  id.df  <- dplyr::filter(df, id == i)
  add.df <- rbind(id.df, data.frame(id = rep(i,add.reps), rep = max(id.df$rep) + add.reps, val = rnorm(add.reps, median(id.df$val), mad(id.df$val)), stringsAsFactors = F))
}))
)

 new.df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(all.ids, function(i) {     id.df <- dplyr::filter(df, id == i)     add.df <- rbind(id.df, data.frame(id = rep(i, add.reps),          rep = max(id.df$rep) + add.reps, val = rnorm(add.reps,              median(id.df$val), mad(id.df$val)), stringsAsFactors = F)) }))
      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 212.9906 225.1345 371.9314 260.9686 332.5619 1621.586   100
```

vs.

```
microbenchmark(
new.df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$id), function(x) rbind(x,
                                                                    data.frame(id = rep(unique(x$id), add.reps), rep = max(x$rep) + add.reps,
                                                                               val = rnorm(add.reps, median(x$val), mad(x$val)), stringsAsFactors = F))))
)

 new.df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$id), function(x) rbind(x,      data.frame(id = rep(unique(x$id), add.reps), rep = max(x$rep) +          add.reps, val = rnorm(add.reps, median(x$val), mad(x$val)),          stringsAsFactors = F))))
      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
 133.8357 135.1846 202.9654 137.2722 160.5121 1401.03   100
```

I wonder if this can still be further improved